# I need help to store radio-button in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, survey

I'm working on simple survey I need to store answers in mysql database.(I'm using *radio button*)

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I don't see a question, but for the sake of being a nice guy, it is like getting any other data from a form. Just post the value to your script and insert it.

Comment: That's the sort of question where the asker doesn't know how to code or use a database, but we're supposed to figure it out for them.

Comment: @DanyCaissy, If by that you mean the type of question where we are supposed to do their job for them, then I agree. Mohamed, If you want to receive help on StackOverflow, you should read the StackOverflow [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for how to ask a good question. Here is a summary of the biggest things (IMHO) that are missing from your question: Demonstration that you have tried to do the work/research your self; code/markup of any kind; examples of any kind; details of your goal and problem; an actual question of any kind

Comment: In addition to the above - I would like to point out that StackOverflow is a forum where you can find others to HELP you with your problems, not do your job for you. If ever one posts a question where others can plainly see that members posting comments are putting more time and thought in than the person who asked the question then there is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a form with a radio in your html

```
<form action="submitTarget.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Options:</legend>
        Option One   <input type="radio" name="optionSelected" value="one"/>
        Option Two   <input type="radio" name="optionSelected" value="two"/>
        Option Three <input type="radio" name="optionSelected" value="three"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

On your PHP side(if you use php) get the post value, construct you statement and execute it:

```
$selectedValue = $_POST["optionSelected"];
$statement = " INSERT INTO MyTable(option_name) VALUES($selectedValue) ";
```

Obviously this is to illustrate the principle you need to do a lot more if you want to create a nice product.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks guys but I still have problem is with checkbox value only the last value is stored in the db

Comment: @sam: Could you please kindly tell me if I could insert the result of multiple radio buttons and checkboxes in db with one query?if yes, how?(I mean e.g, user answers 10 questions (including radio buttons and checkboxes), I don't want to repeat the query each time for each question.. Thanks